# Conflicting application contexts when combining @EnableWebMvc with @EnableContextResourceLoader (a spring-cloud-aws annotation)

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, spring-cloud, spring-web

I am attempting to integrate with Amazon S3 using spring-cloud-aws. The application is web-based and uses @EnableWebMvc on the configuration. When I add the @EnableContextResourceLoader annotation so that I can access files in S3 buckets, I receive the following exception on boot:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Cannot reinitialize with different application context: current one is [WebApplicationContext for namespace 'apiv1-servlet': startup date [Thu May 28 10:17:58 EDT 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext], passed-in one is [WebApplicationContext for namespace 'apiv1-servlet': startup date [Thu May 28 10:17:58 EDT 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ViewResolverComposite.setApplicationContext(ViewResolverComposite.java:80)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1090)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1760)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor118.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$241(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$8/427109654.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the ApiV1Config class which has the @EnableWebMvc annotation and loads the BullhornIntegrationConfig class (which can be seen further down):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.aquent.api.controller.v1")
@Import({ PropertySourcesConfig.class,
        OrderContainerServiceConfig.class,
        JobPostingServiceConfig.class,
        ZipRecruiterUtilsConfig.class,
        AuthenticationTokenServiceConfig.class,
        BullhornIntegrationConfig.class,
        TruTimeFileServiceConfig.class })
@ImportResource({ "classpath:com/aquent/config/order-service-v2/order-service-v2-beans.xml",
        "classpath:com/aquent/config/activity-service-v1/activity-service-v1-beans.xml",
        "classpath:com/aquent/config/email-service-v2/email-service-v2-beans.xml",
        "classpath:com/aquent/config/email-tracking-service-v1/email-tracking-service-v1-beans.xml",
        "classpath:com/aquent/config/contact-service-v3/contact-service-v3-beans.xml",
        "classpath:com/aquent/config/talent-service-v2/talent-submittal-service-beans.xml",
        "classpath:com/aquent/config/security-service-v1/security-service-beans.xml" })
public class ApiV1Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // Unrelated methods (e.g. overriding configureMessageConverters(), etc.)
}
```

And here is the BullhornIntegrationConfig class which configures the amazon-cloud-aws ecosystem:

```
@Configuration
@EnableContextCredentials(accessKey = "${bullhorn.aws.access-key}", secretKey = "${bullhorn.aws.secret-key}")
@EnableContextRegion(region = "${bullhorn.aws.region}")
@EnableContextResourceLoader
@EnableSqs
public class BullhornIntegrationConfig {

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQS amazonSQS, ResourceIdResolver resourceIdResolver) {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQS, resourceIdResolver);
    }
}
```

If I comment out either the @EnableWebMvc annotation or the @EnableContextResourceLoader annotation, the boot completes normally and I can access the web services (when @EnableWebMvc is present) or the Amazon S3 services (when @EnableContextResourceLoader is present). I have been unable to uncover the source of the conflict.

I have searched for a way that I can manually define the necessary resource loader for accessing the S3 buckets, but I've run into a roadblock attempting to get a reference to the appropriate AmazonS3 instance to use while instantiating a SimpleStorageResourceLoader.

My question is this: how can I either resolve the conflict between the @SpringWebMvc and @EnableContextResourceLoader annotations or manually configure a resource loader for loading S3 files?